# Oil FIlled Geode

Tags: geology, geode

Five weeks ago my dad and I collected geodes near Bedford, Indiana, from private property with the full permission of the owner. While cutting the rocks one produced an unexpected result - oil poured out. I am in search of more information, but am new to this forum and unable to respond to another post due to my status.

Insights appreciated. I have the example and I have photos of the experience immediately after it happened.

Comment: Welcome. [Related](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/q/12704/20559)

Comment: Welcome. What is your question exactly? Something like "How do oil geodes form?"?

Comment: Also looks like Indiana isn't an unexpected spot to find oil in general based upon https://maps.lib.utexas.edu/maps/united_states/shale_gas_and_oil_plays-lower_48_states-2011.jpg ... (https://www.americangeosciences.org/critical-issues/maps/interactive-map-historical-oil-and-gas-production-united-states promises an even neater map charting production history... but doesn't work for me)